# How to programmatically load CSV files in mariadb

Tags: csv, mariadb, import-csv

I'm looking for a method to load CSV files into MariaDB. I'm aware of `LOAD DATA` and `LOAD_FILE` but local_infile is set to OFF and I'm not going to be allowed to turn it on.

So, I'm looking for another way to do it. Part of the requirements is that it is not a manual process. It is to be kicked off by either a MariaDB event or a cron job detect the files once they've been created and then kick off the import. I know the format of the files that need to be imported. Could someone point me to alternative mechanisms as I cannot find anything? Thanks.

Comment: Why are you looking for technical workarounds of a function that suites your needs for an administrative denial? Make the [FILE](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/grant/#file) business case with [secure_file_priv](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/server-system-variables/#secure_file_priv) or [local_infile](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/server-system-variables/#local_infile) for a cron script. Alternatives to strengthen the previous business case [csv engine](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/csv-overview/), [connect engine csv tables](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/connect-csv-and-fmt-table-types/).